# Rollup and typescript bundle is without editor code completion and jump to declaration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, visual-studio-code, rollup

Very new to bundling. My team is used to code completion and being able to jump to the type declaration file of a corresponding component using `command + click` in their editor (VSCode).

However the bundle generated does not come with this behaviour... I don't know how to go form here, or what I am missing. These feature are very important to my team. Any help is appreciated

#### Versions

- typescript: 3.7.5
- rollup: 1.31.0
- rollup-plugin-typescript2: 0.26.0

#### rollup.config.js

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import svgr from '@svgr/rollup';
import url from '@rollup/plugin-url';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import includePaths from 'rollup-plugin-includepaths';

const pkg = require('./package.json');

export default {
  cache: false,
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: { file: pkg.module, format: 'esm' },
  plugins: [
    external({
      preferBuiltins: false,
    }),
    babel({
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      plugins: ['external-helpers'],
      externalHelpers: true, 
    }),
    json(),
    resolve(),
    svgr({
      ref: true,
      svgo: false,
    }),
    typescript({
      clean: true,
      typescript: require('typescript'),
    }),
    url(),
    includePaths({
      paths: ['src'],
    }),
    commonjs({
      namedExports: {
        'prop-types': [
          'oneOfType',
          'func',
          'shape',
          'any',
          'number',
          'object',
          'bool',
          'string',
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["storybook", "dist"]
}
```

#### package.json

*Relevant bits only*

```
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the issue - it was because I was using absolute paths. Changing import paths to relative imports or using a plugin to convert absolute to relative import paths when building fixes this issue.

Comment: What plugin did you use?